# constructor ConferenceRooms in class ConferenceRooms cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Can't figure out this compiling error...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class Bookings here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Bookings
{


int day = 5;
int hour = 8;
boolean RunMeOnce = false;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName;

ConferenceRooms[] conRoom = new ConferenceRooms[3]; // 0 = room 1, 1 = room 2, 2 = room 3
MeetingRooms[] meetRoom = new MeetingRooms[3];
OfficeRooms[] offRoom = new OfficeRooms[3];


public Bookings(String [] args){

}

public void main(){

      if (RunMeOnce = false)
      {
          for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
          conRoom[i] = new ConferenceRooms(); //<<<<<<< ERROR OCCURS HERE
          meetRoom[i] = new MeetingRooms();
          offRoom[i] = new OfficeRooms();
        }
        RunMeOnce = true;
    }
      System.out.println("Hello and welcome to One Trinity Greens Room Booking, please choose an option from the list below.");
      System.out.println("1. View availabile rooms");
      System.out.println("2. Make a booking");
      System.out.println("3. Amend a booking");
      System.out.println("4. Delete a booking");
        int selection = input.nextInt();

        switch(selection){

            case 1:
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    System.out.println("Conference Rooms " + i+1);
                    conRoom[i].conferenceBookings();
                    System.out.println("Meeting Rooms " + i+1);
                    meetRoom[i].meetingBookings();
                    System.out.println("Office Rooms " + i+1);
                    offRoom[i].officeBookings();
                }
            break;

            case 2:

            break;

            case 3:

            break;

            case 4:

            break;
        }


}

public void searchRooms(){


}

public void accessAvailability(){


}

public void viewBookings(){


}

public void searchBusiness(){


}

public void addBooking(){


}

public void deleteAllBookings(){


}

public void amendBooking(){


}

public void cancelBooking(){


}



}
```

---

```
public ConferenceRooms(String pbusinessName, String proomType, String pavailability, String proomInformation, String pmeetingBookings){

super(pbusinessName, proomType, pavailability);
       roomInformation = proomInformation;


}
```

Comment: Without having the complete code, this cannot be answered. Where is the ConferenceRoom class?

Comment: It would be great, If you show us `ConferenceRooms` class

Comment: Also, what's the error?

Comment: @MartinDinov Error is in title :) Seems he provided a custom constructor and  not providing any args.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, ah didn't really read it properly :)

Comment: @dcmagpies - Sorry man.. I think you have to go back and relearn the basics... You will have a lot of errors/problems if you dont...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh My.. you have a lot of errors...

```
1. boolean RunMeOnce = false; // '=' is assigning, '=='  is comparing
```

This is not declared as static . So, you will need an object of type Bookings to call it.
Change your code in main() to

```
Bookings bk = new Bookings(); 
if (bk.RunMeOnce)

2. You dont need 2 Scanners to the same Stream (InputStream)

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

3. Show us your conferenceRoom and other classes for discovering more errors :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the constructor correctly. If the ConferenceRooms constructor you've provided is the only one you have, then it's clear why you're getting the error: provide the missing arguments!